# Batch script to generate folders for specific year month, week & weekday

Tags: batch-file

Couple of a last days i´ve been searching for answer for this question. There is a lot of answers dealing with batch folder creation for whole year, but not enough specific so i would appreciate answer very much.

So i would like to have this kind of folder structure as it follows

```
2017 (for example main folder for year 2017)  
01_JAN....12_DEC (subfolders with names of month )  
01JAN/01_01_SUN, 02_01_MON, 03_01_TUE...etc  (subsub folders with week day name at the end)
```

also if its possible it would be fine to include also week numbers here too although i would be satisfied with week days ie

```
01JAN/01_01_SUN-52, 02_01_MON-01, 03_01_TUE-01...09_01_MON-02 etc with weekdays starts with monday
```

im planning to use this in project of automation of production of barcode

thank you!
p.s.
closest i got was this example that i manage to found [How do I write a batch script to generate folders for each month, day and year?](https://superuser.com/questions/483045/how-do-i-write-a-batch-script-to-generate-folders-for-each-month-day-and-year)

Comment: The answer you linked to shows in detail how to solve this problem, as do [this](https://superuser.com/questions/635854/automate-directory-tree-creation-based-on-date) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/891909/how-do-i-create-a-batch-file-that-will-create-a-folder-for-each-day-of-the-month). If it isn't sufficient, please explain carefully why.

Comment: i dont know how to calculate and put WEEK DAYS NAMES (Mon, Tue,Wen..ect) to the name of Batch created folder for whole year)    That script calculates only for example 01_Jan, 02_Jan ect without corresponding week day name...

Comment: in first example you posted script produces only one folder for current day ie 23.07.2017 ...im looking for script that creates folders for whole year with day and month as integers and also day as day of the week ie 01_01_Sunday                                                                                                        second example is in powershell and i dont even know how to use that :(      i just discovered batchscripting  :)

Comment: You should put the Ean topic into a new question as this one is answered and won't get much attention.

Comment: oh i see, thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with pure batch and the help of several date functions from [Ritchie Lawrence Batchfunctionlibrary](http://ritchielawrence.github.io/batchfunctionlibrary/) published under the [MIT License](https://github.com/ritchielawrence/mtee/blob/master/LICENSE.txt) and other sources.

- This batch converts the start date to a modified julian date
- calculates the end date by adding 364 or in leap years 365.
- iterates all values in between and gennerating the folder names.
- as `MD` will create intermediate folders it is only necessary to create the day folder.
- the batch uses the ISO calendar week what implies that the first/last days may belong to a week from prev/next year - this differing year is appended in parentheses.

Sample output created in 30 seconds on a ramdisk:
**EDIT Streamlined version with less calls and same output takes 8secs**

```
> tree a:\
A:\
├───2017
│   ├───01_Jan
│   │   ├───01_01_Sun-52(2016)
│   │   ├───02_01_Mon-01
│   │   ├───03_01_Tue-01
│   │   ├───04_01_Wed-01
...
│   │   ├───30_01_Mon-05
│   │   └───31_01_Tue-05
│   ├───02_Feb
│   │   ├───01_02_Wed-05
│   │   ├───02_02_Thu-05
...
```

And here the lengthy batch
(change variable Base to contain your base folder):

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\07\23\SO_45269929.cmd
:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269929/batch-script-to-generate-folders-for-specific-Year-month-and-day
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Base=C:\Test\2"
Set "Year=%~1"
If not defined Year Set /P "Year=Enter Year (4 places) yyyy :"

:: To be more efficient get month/day nmaes array
For %%A in (:01:Jan:Mon: :02:Feb:Tue: :03:Mar:Wed:  :04:Apr:Thu:
            :05:May:Fri:  :06:Jun:Sat: :07:Jul:Sun: :08:Aug::
            :09:Sep:: :10:Oct:: :11:Nov:: :12:Dec::
) do for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%l in ("%%A") do (
    set "MonN[%%l]=%%m"
    set "DayN[%%l]=%%n"
)
Call :DateToMJD %Year% 01 01 StartDate
Call :DateToMJD %Year% 12 31 EndDate

Echo [%date% %time%] Start creating folders for Year %Year%
For /L %%M in (%StartDate%,1,%EndDate%) Do Call :GenDay %%M
Echo [%date% %time%] Done  creating folders for Year %Year%
Goto :Eof

:GenDay
Call :MJDToDate  %1 YY MM DD
Call :DateToWeek %YY% %MM% %DD% yn cw dw
Set "Folder=%Base%\%YY%\%MM%_!MonN[%MM%]!\%DD%_%MM%_!DayN[0%dw%]!-%cw%"
If %YY% neq %yn% Set "Folder=%Folder%(%yn%)"
MD "%Folder%"
Goto :Eof
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:DateToMJD %yy% %mm% %dd% MJD
::
:: By:   Ritchie Lawrence, 2002-06-15. Version 1.0
::
:: Func: Returns a Modified Julian Day (MJD) from a UTC date.
::       Reference date (day 0) is Wednesday 17th November 1858. For
::       NT4/2K/XP/2003.
:: Args:
::  %1 Year component used to create MJD, 2 or 4 digits (by val)
::  %2 month component used to create MJD, leading zero ok (by val)
::  %3 day of month used to create MJD, leading zero ok (by val)
::  %4 var to receive MJD (by ref)
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set yy=%1&set mm=%2&set dd=%3
if 1%yy% LSS 200 if 1%yy% LSS 170 (set yy=20%yy%) else (set yy=19%yy%)
Set /a dd=100%dd%%%100,mm=100%mm%%%100
Set /a z=14-mm,z/=12,y=yy+4800-z,m=mm+12*z-3,j=153*m+2
Set /a j=j/5+dd+y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-2432046
Endlocal&set %4=%j%&Goto :Eof
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:MJDToDate %MJD% yy mm dd
::
:: By:   Ritchie Lawrence, 2002-06-15. Version 1.1
:: Func:
::  Returns a UTC date from a Modified Julian Day (MJD). Reference
::  date (day 0) is Wednesday 17th November 1858. For NT4/2K/XP/2003.
:: 
:: Args: %1 MJD used to create calEndar date (by val)
::       %2 var to receive Year component, 4 digits (by ref)
::       %3 var to receive month component, 2 digits, 01-12 (by ref)
::       %4 var to receive day of month, 2 digits, 01-31 (by ref)
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set /a a=%1+2432045,b=4*a+3,b/=146097,c=-b*146097,c/=4,c+=a
Set /a d=4*c+3,d/=1461,e=-1461*d,e/=4,e+=c,m=5*e+2,m/=153,dd=153*m+2
Set /a dd/=5,dd=-dd+e+1,mm=-m/10,mm*=12,mm+=m+3,yy=b*100+d-4800+m/10
(if %mm% LSS 10 set mm=0%mm%)&(if %dd% LSS 10 set dd=0%dd%)
Endlocal&set %2=%yy%&set %3=%mm%&set %4=%dd%&Goto :Eof
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:DateToWeek %yy% %mm% %dd% yn cw dw
::
:: By:   Ritchie Lawrence, Updated 2002-11-20. Version 1.1
::
:: Func: Returns an ISO 8601 Week date from a calEndar date.
::       For NT4/2000/XP/2003.
:: 
:: Args: %1 Year component to be converted, 2 or 4 digits (by val)
::       %2 month component to be converted, leading zero ok (by val)
::       %3 day of month to be converted, leading zero ok (by val)
::       %4 var to receive Year, 4 digits (by ref)
::       %5 var to receive calEndar week, 2 digits, 01 to 53 (by ref)
::       %6 var to receive day of week, 1 digit, 1 to 7 (by ref)
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set yy=%1&set mm=%2&set dd=%3
if 1%yy% LSS 200 if 1%yy% LSS 170 (set yy=20%yy%) else (set yy=19%yy%)
Set /a dd=100%dd%%%100,mm=100%mm%%%100
Set /a z=14-mm,z/=12,y=yy+4800-z,m=mm+12*z-3,Jd=153*m+2
Set /a Jd=Jd/5+dd+y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-32045
Set /a y=yy+4798,Jp=y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-31738,t=Jp+3,Jp=t-t%%7
Set /a y=yy+4799,Jt=y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-31738,t=Jt+3,Jt=t-t%%7
Set /a y=yy+4800,Jn=y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-31738,t=Jn+3,Jn=t-t%%7
Set /a Jr=%Jp%,yn=yy-1,yn+=Jd/Jt,yn+=Jd/Jn
if %Jd% GEQ %Jn% (set /a Jr=%Jn%) else (if %Jd% GEQ %Jt% set /a Jr=%Jt%)
Set /a diff=Jd-Jr,cw=diff/7+1,wd=diff%%7,wd+=1
if %cw% LSS 10 set cw=0%cw%
Endlocal&set %4=%yn%&set %5=%cw%&set %6=%wd%&Goto :Eof
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer it works like a charm  :)                       also thank you for editing the question  :)

Answer (score 2):

This Batch file do what you want.

**EDIT:** I added the following modifications:
1- The year is read from keyboard instead of get from a parameter.
2- The year folder is created in the same folder where the Batch file is placed.
3- A minor bug in "week 53" was fixed.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /P "year=Enter desired year: "

rem Select the base folder
cd "%~P0"

rem Initialize all variables
set i=0
for %%a in (Jan:31 Feb:28 Mar:31 Apr:30 May:31 Jun:30 Jul:31 Aug:31 Sep:30 Oct:31 Nov:30 Dec:31) do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%m in ("%%a") do (
      set /A i+=1
      set "month[!i!]=%%m"
      set "dpm[!i!]=%%n"
   )
)
set /A "dpm[2]+=^!(year%%4), d=((year+4799)*1461/4-(year+4899)/100*3/4+1)%%7*3, rot=^!d+((d-15)>>31)+1, week=101+51*rot"
if %d% equ 3 set "week=100"
set "dow=SunMonTueWedThuFriSat"
set "dow=!dow:~%d%!!dow:~0,%d%!"

rem Create the folders
md %year%
cd %year%
for /L %%m in (1,1,12) do (
   set "m=0%%m"
   set "m=!m:~-2!"
   md !m!_!month[%%m]!
   cd !m!_!month[%%m]!
   for /L %%d in (1,1,!dpm[%%m]!) do (
      set "d=0%%d"
      if "!dow:~0,3!" equ "Mon" set /A week+=1 & if !week!!rot! equ 1531 set "week=101"
      md !d:~-2!_!m!_!dow:~0,3!-!week:~1!
      set "dow=!dow:~3!!dow:~0,3!"
   )
   cd ..
)
```

Comment: I tried to make it work this batch file you posted but it seems i m unable to execute it...(there is no any prompt to enter year or smt) still thank you for your time  :)

Comment: I like your batch +1, in speed speed terms compared to mine ftl. But rarely it doesn't match http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date. I.e. 2004=>2005,2009=>2010,2015=>2016 etc. when there is a 53rd week reaching into the next year.

Comment: @eshu: Below the code there was this indication: _"You must give the desired year in the parameter"_. **`:/`** I modified the program to prompt for the year...

Comment: @LotPings: yes, but this is a small detail very easy to fix... See my edit

Comment: @LotPings: yes, but the OP can change the selected answer at any moment! **`;-)`**

Comment: @Aacini  it works now , quick and simple  Thank you!

Comment: That is good! However, you have not rewarded my efforts in any way... **`:(`** You didn't even upvoted my answer and you should select as "Best answer" the one that is most useful to you. I suggest you to be more patient when you select the Best answer (although you may change it if you wish).

Comment: @Aacini ... sorry im new here...i tried to upvote your answer to earlier question but i couldnt...just afer your comment i realised im qualified to do so, so i did!   thank you again for your time and effort too!

Answer (score 1):

A PowerShell answer is much more compact due to intrinsic date functions,
here without the weeks:

```
$Base = 'D:\Test'
$Year = 2017
$StartDate = Get-Date -Year $Year -Month 1  -Day 1
$EndDate   = Get-Date -Year $Year -Month 12 -Day 31
$DateRange = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End $EndDate
0..$DateRange.Days|ForEach-Object {
    MD $($Base+$StartDate.AddDays($_).ToString('\\yyyy\\MM_MMM\\dd_MM_ddd'))
}
```

Comment: i managed to enable powershell on my pc and tried this answer and also, i have to confirm it works like a charm  (only without weekdays)                          thank you again, im so happy for this it saves a lot of time and makes work easier and more reliable  :)