# Batch script to move EAN 13 barcode files to designated YMD folders

Tags: batch-file

I have managed to batch produce barcodes for one publication for whole year. Now need batch script to move files to designated folders.(so i wouldn have to do it manually .also it saves a lot of time and decrease possiblities of error)

Files are situated in folder named C:Barcode

Files have structure like this:

for each day in a week there is EAN 13 barcode witch structure is:

```
977133156901600117 THRU 977133156901605217  52 FILES FOR MON 
977133156902300117 THRU 977133156902305217  52 FILES FOR TUE
977133156903000117 THRU 977133156903005217  52 FILES FOR WED
977133156904700117 THRU 977133156904705217  52 FILES FOR THU
385989238246900117 THRU 385989238246900117  52 FILES FOR FRI
977133156906100117 THRU 977133156906105217  52 FILES FOR SAT
977133156907800117 THRU 977133156907805217  52 FILES FOR SUN
```

script should take this file 977133156901600117 and put in folder 02_01_MON_01

take file 977133156902300117 and put it in the folder 03_01_TUE_01

......

take file 977133156907805217 and put it in the folder 31_12_SUN-52

explanation

9771331569-01-60-01-17  --- first 01 from left tells that this is Monday and second 01 tells that this is first week of the year

9771331569-02-30-01-17 --- 02 tells that its Tuesday and 01 tells that this is first week of the year

etc....

38598923824690-01-17 ---  38598923824690 unique number tells that this it Friday and 01 tells its first week of the year

....

9771331569-07-80-52-17  --- 07 tells that this is Sunday and 52 tells its the 52 week of the year

I would like batch script to move those files to folder structure as it follows:
(witch is kindly provided by stack member @LotPings  in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269929/batch-script-to-generate-folders-for-specific-year-month-week-weekday))

```
2017/o1_JAN/01_01_SUN_52(2016)
            02_01_MON_01
            03_01_TUE_01
            04_01_WED_01
            ............
            08_01_SUN_01
            09_01_MON_02
            10_01_TUE_02
            ............
```

where last two diggits represents a week of that year

ie. for example to move file 977133156901600117 to folder 02_01_MON_01
 ( barcode for first day in week (MON) and first week in a year (01) to folder  02_01_MON_01

Comment: Two things: The codes provided for Friday are massively breaking out of the scheme provided and you should show the effort you made. This is no scripting service that provides you with free code :) And `977133156904705217` for Saturday cannot be correct after your scheme either because of the 04 (at least that is if I understand that pattern correctly).

Comment: You should check if the week numbers in your barcodes comply with ISO8601 which I used in my batch/script. There also is a `WeekToDate` function in [Ritchie Lawrence Batchfunctionlibrary](http://ritchielawrence.github.io/batchfunctionlibrary/) So you can iterate the barcodes (do they have an extension?) and split the names with substrings to generate a yyyyMMdd date from yy cw dow. The appended mont/day names are a nuisance here.

Comment: `385989238246900117` would relate to day 46 of week 1 in 2017. There were only 7 days in week 1 of 2017, _in my locale at least_. I also note that you're wishing to use a folder structure utilising months, `JAN`, `FEB`, `MAR`, `APR`, `MAY`, `JUN`, `JUL`, `AUG`, `SEP`, `AUG` `NOV` & `DEC`. Those however are not defined in your barcodes so your batch file may need a lookup table or complex routine in order to determine which week numbers belonged specifically to which month in any specific year.

Comment: @geisterfurz007     yes, that`s correct because fridays number is not ISSN number but rather a barcode number related to some other publication...still fridays number is unique and it does not breaks with same logic as numbers for other days

Comment: @geisterfurz007                                                                                        you are right about number for saturday ,but its fixed now... about effort...i have only faint idea about what it should be done...there are two variables to consider week number (1-52) and week day (1-7)...fridays number can be fix variable and week as variable

Comment: @Compo number for friday isnt classical EAN 13 number for newspapers in this case...its number for some other kind of publication and the logic isnt same as the logic for numbers for other days ...this part 3859892382469 is fixed...basically newspappers goes out every day of the week so it has ISSN number for each day..3859892382469 on the other hand is a number for publications that are publish on weekly or monthly basis...so that numbers are fixed only number of week is changing depending on week on witch its published

Comment: You are going to have to update you post, by way of [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45280824/edit), with a full and complete explanation of every possible filename and the logic behing naming/moving each one then!

Comment: The date (day of month) can be easily derived from the week number using the same approach I used in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45272233/778560) to your previous question...

Comment: @Aacini i saw edited answer for last question and im thankin` you for that! :)

Comment: @Aacini tell me please, is it possible then to use this your approach to move a files in one go?

Comment: Yes, of course. The same code can move your files with just a few lines more. It may also create folders just for the existing files and/or report at end which folders were not created. However, you should read first my last comment at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45272233/778560) to your previous question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements and exceptions this result should be what you want:

```
C:\TEST\2\2017
├───01_Jan
│   ├───01_01_Sun-52(2016)
│   ├───02_01_Mon-01
│   │       977133156901600117
│   ├───03_01_Tue-01
│   │       977133156902300117
│   ├───04_01_Wed-01
│   │       977133156903000117
│   ├───05_01_Thu-01
│   │       977133156904700117
│   ├───06_01_Fri-01
│   │       385989238246900117
│   ├───07_01_Sat-01
│   │       977133156906100117
│   ├───08_01_Sun-01
│   │       977133156907800117
│   ├───09_01_Mon-02
│   │       977133156901600217
│   ├───10_01_Tue-02
│   │       977133156902300217
│   ├───11_01_Wed-02
│   │       977133156903000217
│   ├───12_01_Thu-02
│   │       977133156904700217
│   ├───13_01_Fri-02
│   │       385989238246900217
│   ├───14_01_Sat-02
│   │       977133156906100217
│   ├───15_01_Sun-02
│   │       977133156907800217
│   ├───16_01_Mon-03
│   │       977133156901600317
...
```

Still not quite shure if you use the ISO8601 calendar week.
Adjust Base and Barcode folder to suit your environment.

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\07\24\SO_45280824.cmd
:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280824/batch-script-to-move-ean-13-barcode-files-to-designated-ymd-folders
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Base=C:\Test\2"
PushD "C:\Test\2\Barcode"

:: To be more efficient get month/day names array
For %%A in (:01:Jan:Mon: :02:Feb:Tue: :03:Mar:Wed:  :04:Apr:Thu:
            :05:May:Fri:  :06:Jun:Sat: :07:Jul:Sun: :08:Aug::
            :09:Sep:: :10:Oct:: :11:Nov:: :12:Dec::
) do for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%l in ("%%A") do (
    set "MonN[%%l]=%%m"
    set "DayN[%%l]=%%n"
)
For %%F in (*) Do Call :GetFolder %%F

Pause
PopD
Goto :Eof

:GetFolder
Rem   012345678901234567
Rem   977133156901600117
Rem  ISSN       d# wk#   
Rem      publica  C   yy

Set "File=%~1"
Set "yn=20%File:~16,2%
Set "cw=%File:~14,2%
Set "dw=%File:~10,2%
If "%File:~0,13%" Equ "3859892382469" Set "dw=05"
Call :WeekToDate %yn% %cw% %dw% yy mm dd
Set "Folder=%Base%\%yy%\%mm%_!MonN[%mm%]!\%dd%_%mm%_!DayN[%dw%]!-%cw%"
If %YY% neq %yn% Set "Folder=%Folder%(%yy%)"
IF exist "%Folder%" (
  Move %1 "%Folder%" >Nul 2>&1
  Echo moved %1 =^> "%Folder%"
) Else (
  Echo Check %1 "%Folder%"
  Pause
)
Goto :Eof

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:WeekToDate %yn% %cw% %dw% yy mm dd
::
:: By:   Ritchie Lawrence, 2002-10-04. Version 1.0
::
:: Func: Returns a calEndar date from an ISO 8601 Week date.
::       For NT4/2000/XP/2003.
:: 
:: Args: %1 year to convert, 2 or 4 digits (by val)
::       %2 calEndar week to convert, 2 digits, 01 to 53 (by val)
::       %3 day of week to convert, 1 digit, 1 to 7 (by val)
::       %4 var to receive year, 4 digits (by ref)
::       %5 var to receive month, 2 digits, 01 to 12 (by ref)
::       %6 var to receive day of month, 2 digits, 01 to 31 (by ref)
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set yn=%1&set cw=%2&set dw=%3
if 1%yy% LSS 200 if 1%yy% LSS 170 (set yy=20%yy%) else (set yy=19%yy%)
Set /a cw=100%cw%%%100,d=3210654
Set /a z=14-1,z/=12,y=yn+4800-z,m=1+12*z-3,Jt=153*m+2
Set /a Jt=Jt/5+1+y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-32045,wt=Jt%%7
Call set at=%%d:~%wt%,1%%&set /a Jt=at+Jt-3 
Set /a Jt=Jt+7*cw+dw-9,a=Jt+32045,b=4*a+3,b/=146097,c=-b*146097,c/=4,c+=a
Set /a d=4*c+3,d/=1461,e=-1461*d,e/=4,e+=c,m=5*e+2,m/=153,dd=153*m+2,dd/=5
Set /a dd=-dd+e+1,mm=-m/10,mm*=12,mm+=m+3,yy=b*100+d-4800+m/10
(if %mm% LSS 10 set mm=0%mm%)&(if %dd% LSS 10 set dd=0%dd%)
Endlocal&set %4=%yy%&set %5=%mm%&set %6=%dd%&Goto :Eof
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: maybe instead of `If "%File:~0,13%" Equ "3859892382469" ` better something like `if "%dw%" gtr "07"` ? (there might be more than one weekly publication (in the future?)). Depends, on the logic of "weekly".

Comment: thank you for the answer, but yes something is happening with dates and frankly i just dont know what is happening...and i dont know how to check witch standard for calendar week is in use here in croatia...but today is monday 30 week of year

Comment: @Stephan  weekly means once a week... every weekly publication has determined day on witch its published and that is not changing...thx for the answer though  :)

Comment: See details of [ISO8601 here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) especially [week dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates)

Comment: i was reading that also...what do you think its a problem with it? i mean in calendar today is Monday of 30`s week in a year...  or maye you think thats something wrong with my windows locale?

Comment: @LotPings  do i have to create folders for 2017 in C:\Test\2, or this second batch script should generate it by itself?

Comment: No change to fit your environment.

Comment: i see, no problem, thank you very much for your time and your answers..i should and i am grateful to have resolved this first part of an issue...thanks though   :)

Comment: @LotPings it runs beautifuly! you were wright i made mistake in naming of the barcodes so i remaned them and in a matter of seconds it filled up those folders!  Thank you very much for this! it saved me from so much manual work.. i found this batch scripting  just recently and this saves so much times and unnecessary hassle...thank you for helping me...wish you a luck and good life...peace brother!  :D