# BATCH FILE - create folders with every WORKING DAY (no saturday and sunday)

Tags: batch-file

I would like to edit the following batch code in order to create a folder with every working day of the year and skip saturday and sunday (i guess it should create 5 consecutive days and skip the next 2)
I would also like the batch file to

1. skip creating folders for each month(a january folder, a february folder etc) and have all days of the year in the same folder.
2. add two extra folders in each day folder with 'morning' and 'afternoon'

Ex:

```
C:\Users\alex\Desktop\2022\1 Jan\Morning
C:\Users\alex\Desktop\2022\1 Jan\Afternoon
```

all the way to

```
C:\Users\alex\Desktop\2022\31 Dec\Morning
C:\Users\alex\Desktop\2022\31 Dec\Afternoon
```

(it would not create 31 dec folder because thats a saturday)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\years"
SET /p year=### Enter Year [e.g. 2014]:
IF NOT DEFINED year GOTO :EOF 
SET year=%year:,=%
IF %year% lss 100 SET /a year=2000+year
IF %year% gtr 1901 IF %year% lss 2099 GOTO generate
ECHO year entered out of range 1901..2099
GOTO :eof

:generate
MD "%sourcedir%"
SET /a feb=year %% 4
IF %feb%==0 (SET "feb=02,February,29") ELSE (SET "feb=02,February,28")
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
MKDIR %year%
CD %year%
FOR %%a IN ("01,January,31" "%feb%" "03,March,31" "04,April,30" "05,May,31" "06,June,30" "07,July,31" "08,August,31" "09,September,30" "10,October,31" "11,November,30" "12,December,31") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=," %%b IN (%%a) DO (
  SET "month=%%c"
  SET "month=!month:~0,3!"
  MKDIR %%b_%%c
  pushd %%b_%%c
  FOR /l %%q IN (1,1,%%d) DO MD %%q-!month!-%year%
  popd
 )
)
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: What about bank/public holidays, which are also generally not 'working' days. If you were only interested in weekdays, i.e. the days of a week excluding weekends, then it would have been better to say so, without adding the confusion of using the term 'working'. BTW, I strongly advise that you do not consider performing this task using a batch file only, please get the assistance of PowerShell, or some other utility, which has support for date objects.

Comment: If you want a pure `batch-file` solution many of Ritchie Lawrence's script  can do what yo want.  The majority of code you need is all in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269929/batch-script-to-generate-folders-for-specific-year-month-week-weekday).  He sets day of week with the numbers 1 to 7.  Not sure if 1 represents Sunday or Monday though.

Answer (score 0):

Not pure batch, but you can use `powershell` to help a bit.

```
@echo off
set "sourcedir=U:\years"
set /p year=### Enter Year [e.g. 2014]:
echo 0..365 ^| %% { $date = Get-Date "%year%-01-01";$date = $date.AddDays($_).ToString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy");Write-Host $date"" }>tmp.ps1
for /F "tokens=1-4*" %%a in ('powershell .\tmp.ps1') do (
    if "%%~d" == "2022" if not "%%a" == "Saturday" if not "%%a" == "Sunday" (
        echo mkdir "%sourcedir%\%%c %%d\%%a %%b\Morning"
        echo mkdir "%sourcedir%\%%c %%d\%%a %%b\Afternoon"
  )
)
del /Q tmp.ps1
```

PS!! you don't have to use the temp file at all, I just don't have the time now to do all the escaping of special characters, but it will help you in the right direction, if you can use hybrids.

You can move the year/month/days around as you please. If you want short Month and Day (Dec, Mon instead of December Monday) change the format in the `powershell` portion:

```
echo 0..365 ^| %% { $date = Get-Date "%year%-01-01";$date = $date.AddDays($_).ToString("ddd dd MMM yyyy");Write-Host $date"" }>tmp.ps1
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple task when you use the right method and formulae:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "i=0"
for %%a in (Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun) do (
   set "DayOfWeek[!i!]=%%a"
   set /A i+=1
)

set /P "Year=Enter year: "
set /A "leap=28+^!(Year%%4)*^!^!(Year%%400)"
set "MonthNameDays=Jan:31 Feb:%leap% Mar:31 Apr:30 May:31 Jun:30 Jul:31 Aug:31 Sep:30 Oct:31 Nov:30 Dec:31"

rem Get Julian Day Number of Jan/01 of given year
rem adjusted as multiple of day of week: JDN % 7 = 0..6 for Mon..Sun
rem Reference: http://www.hermetic.ch/cal_stud/jdn.htm#comp

set /A "JDN=(1461*(Year+4799))/4+4037/12-(3*((Year+4899)/100))/4-1, MM=100"

for %%a in (%MonthNameDays%) do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%x in ("%%a") do (
   set /A MM+=1
   ECHO md "!MM:~1! %%x"
   ECHO pushd "!MM:~1! %%x"
   for /L %%d in (1,1,%%y) do (
      set /A "JDN+=1, DOW=JDN%%7, DD=100+%%d"
      if !DOW! lss 5 (
         for %%w in (!DOW!) do (
            ECHO md "!DD:~-2! !DayOfWeek[%%w]!"
         )
      )
   )
   ECHO popd
)
```

I focused on the core point of generate folders for Mon..Fri days of week, so I not included some minor details, like generate Morning/Afternoon folders. Also, I just echoed the "MD" commands...

Answer (score 0):

As per my earlier comment, the following batch file gets the assistance of PowerShell:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

:AskYear
ClS
Set "YYYY="
Set /P "YYYY=Please enter a four digit year from 1900 to 2099 incl.>"
Set YYYY 2>NUL|%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R^
 "^YYYY=19[0123456789][0123456789]$ ^YYYY=20[0123456789][0123456789]$" 1>NUL || GoTo AskYear
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile^
 "$beginningOfYear = Get-Date -Year %YYYY% -Month 1 -Day 1 -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0;"^
 "$endOfYear = ($beginningOfYear).AddYears(1).AddSeconds(-1);"^
 "While ($beginningOfYear -LE $endOfYear) {"^
 " $beginningOfYear = ($beginningOfYear).AddDays(1);"^
 " If ($beginningOfYear.DayOfWeek -GT 0) {"^
 "  If ($beginningOfYear.DayOfWeek -LT 6) {"^
 "   $children=@('Morning','Afternoon');"^
 "   ForEach ($i In $children) {"^
 "    md \"$($beginningOfYear.ToString('yyyy\\d MMM'))\$i\"}}}}"
```

The above example assumes that your culture/locale settings use the first day of the week `0` as the last day of the weekend, and the `6` as the first day of the weekend. If your culture/locale settings use `6` and `5` for those two days respectively, then you'd simply change the code accordingly:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

:AskYear
ClS
Set "YYYY="
Set /P "YYYY=Please enter a four digit year from 1900 to 2099 incl.>"
Set YYYY 2>NUL|%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R^
 "^YYYY=19[0123456789][0123456789]$ ^YYYY=20[0123456789][0123456789]$" 1>NUL || GoTo AskYear
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile^
 "$beginningOfYear = Get-Date -Year %YYYY% -Month 1 -Day 1 -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0;"^
 "$endOfYear = ($beginningOfYear).AddYears(1).AddSeconds(-1);"^
 "While ($beginningOfYear -LE $endOfYear) {"^
 " $beginningOfYear = ($beginningOfYear).AddDays(1);"^
 " If ($beginningOfYear.DayOfWeek -LT 5) {"^
 "  $children=@('Morning','Afternoon');"^
 "  ForEach ($i In $children) {"^
 "   md \"$($beginningOfYear.ToString('yyyy\\d MMM'))\$i\"}}}"
```